# Pycharm console and terminal taking different sqlite version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, airflow, airflow-scheduler

[image]
I was running Airflow schedular but got the error: ***airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: sqlite C library version too old (3.7.17< 3.15.0).***
I had installed the latest SQLite but still getting the same error.i found that pycharm console and terminal taking different sqlite version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have different python "environments" used in both and each of those environments has different sqlite libraries.

See more details in Airflow's troubleshooting section of sqlite database here:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-sqlite-database

Comment: I had followed the same link, still getting the same issues. Please suggest what to do to match the environments

Comment: make sure same python is used. You need to understand  what you do there. I suggest to start with https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html and learn all the ropes how you configure python interpreter you use